# Rails 4, Devise - Error messages on Login aren't working properply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Piece of code on github: http://bit.ly/ZMSJXQ

1) On Login, I get **no error messages** if:

- email doesn't exist in db
- password is empty
- password is wrong

`devise_error_messages!` is empty as `resource.errors` is empty.
Looks like resource doesn't get validated. Why?

---

2) If I run `resource.valid?` then `resource.errors` returns `:email=>["has already been taken"], :password=>["can't be blank"]`

I get error messages but they're not correct. 'Email has already been taken' doesn't make sense on log in. Why?

(Sign up, Reset password etc. work fine.)

Comment: Did you try with devise's helper devise_error_messages! ?

Comment: Yes, returns empty string.

Comment: @Helen how did you set up devise? Can you post model code?

Comment: Sure, here's the user model http://bitly.com/10sFE7x

Answer (score 10):

`devise_error_messages!` is only a helper to return a formatted list of `resource.errors`. Some devise failure messages are set in rails's flash object though. Somewhere in your layout you should render those flash messages:

```
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" %>
<%- end -%>
```